# How do I choose width for a set of text fields?

Tags: website-design, page-layout, design-principles

A programmer myself, I find it hard to make certain seemingly simple design decisions.
Currently I'm sketching a signup form for a website, and I want to keep the design really simple.

There are several sections in the form, which I decided to be best separated by horizontal lines:

[image: signup form mockup]

However I'm *really* not sure about:

- **widths of the text fields**
- **widths of the separators**

I think it's best to keep the width consistent for at least elements of the same type (see above).
Is this a common practice?

Should I also align separators with the fields, or maybe with the header?
Are there any commonly accepted recommendations on this?

Answer (score 2):

Best practices in this kind of situation are:

- Labels right aligned with right edges precisely aligned vertically.
- Left edges of fields and separators precisely aligned vertically. Also applies to the left radio button.
- Fields the same width except where it makes no sense (as in your second field).
- Length of the rules (separators) isn't critical, but they will make the most sense if they're the same width as the headline.
- An imaginary box around the entire form should be offset from the left or centered to correspond with the layout of other pages on the site.